# How do I maintain multi-table integrity across multiple selects in SQLAlchemy in Pyramid?

Tags: python, transactions, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I'm trying to build a Pyramid application. I started with the SQLAlchemy scaffolding. I'm running into a issue and I'm wondering what the best way is to address it. In one of my views I need to select a lot of rows from two unrelated tables. I need to make sure no rows were inserted into the second table between the time I selected the rows from the first table and the time I selected the rows from the second table.

I have three models, `Node`, `Test`, and `Tasking`. Both `Nodes` and `Tests` have quite a bit of metadata. Given a list of `Nodes` and a list of `Tests`, a global list of `Taskings` can be created. For example, we could have three `Nodes`, `a`, `b`, and `c` and two `Tests` "we need one node to do task `P`" and "we need two nodes to do task `Q`".

From that information, three `Tasks` should be created. For example:

1. "Node `a` should do task `P`"
2. "Node `b` should do task `Q`"
3. "Node `c` should do task `Q`"

Now, I'm attempting to provide a REST API for this. The vast majority of time clients will be requesting the list of `Tasks`, so that needs to be fast. However, sometimes a client might add a `Node` or a `Test`. When that happens, I need the entire list of `Tasks` to be regenerated.

Here's a rough example:

```
@view_config(route_name='list_taskings')
def list_taskings(request):
    return DBSession.Query(Tasking).all()

@view_config(route_name='add_node')
def add_node(request):
    DBSession.add(Node())
    _update_taskings()

@view_config(route_name='add_test')
def add_test(request):
    DBSession.add(Test())
    _update_taskings()

def _update_taskings():
    nodes = DBSession.query(Node).all()
    tests = DBSession.query(Test).all()

    # Process...

    Tasking.query.delete()
    for t in taskings:
        DBSession.add(t)
```

I'm using the default Pyramid SQLAlchemy scaffolding. So, each request auto starts a transaction. So, if `_update_tasking` is called from one request (say `add_node`), then the new node will be added to the local `DBSession`, and querying for all `Nodes` and `Tests` in `_update_tasking` will return that new element. In addition, deleting all existing `Taskings` and adding the newly computed ones is also safe.

I have two problems:

1. What happens if a new row is added into the `Tests` table between the time I get my list of `nodes` and my list of `tests` in `_update_taskings`? In my real world production system these selects are close together but not right next to each other. There is the possibility of a race condition.
2. How do I ensure two requests that will update the `Taskings` don't overwrite each other? For example, imagine if our existing system had one `Node` and one `Test`. Two requests come in at the same, one to add a `Node` and one to add a `Test`. Even if problem #1 wasn't an issue and I knew that each request's pair of selects represented "a single instance of time in the database", there's still the problem of one request overriding the other. If the first request finishes first with now two `Nodes` and one `Test`, the second request will still be selecting the old data (potentially) and will generate a list of `Taskings` with one `Node` and two `Tests`.

So, what's the best way to deal with this? I'm using SQLite for development and PostgreSQL in production, but I'd like a database agnostic solution. I'm not worried about other applications accessing this database. My REST API will be the only access mechanism. Should I put a lock around any of requests that mutate the database (adding a `Node` or a `Test`)? Should I lock the database somehow?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [serializable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability) transaction isolation level should prevent both problems. If one transaction modifies the data that can affect results of previous reads in another transaction, there is a serialization conflict. Only one transaction wins, all others are aborted by the database to be restarted by the client. SQLite does this by locking the whole database, PostgreSQL employs much more complex mechanism (see [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) for details). Unfortunately, there is no portable sqlalchemic way to catch serialization anomaly and retry. You need to write DB-specific code to reliably distinguish it from other errors.

I've put up a sample program with two threads concurrently modifying the data (a very basic reproduction of your scheme), running into conflicts and retrying:

https://gist.github.com/khayrov/6291557

With Pyramid transaction middleware and Zope transaction manager in use that would be even easier. After catching serialization error, instead of retrying manually, raise `TransientError` and middleware will retry the whole request up to `tm.attempts` (in the paster config) times.

```
from transaction.interfaces import TransientError

class SerializationConflictError(TransientError):
    def __init__(self, orig):
        self.orig = orig
```

You can even write your own middleware sitting below `pyramid_tm` in the stack that will catch serialization errors and translate them to transient errors transparently.

```
def retry_serializable_tween_factory(handler, registry):

    def retry_tween(request):
        try:
            return handler(request)
        except DBAPIError, e:
            orig = e.orig
            if getattr(orig, 'pgcode', None) == '40001':
                raise SerializationConflictError(e)
            elif isinstance(orig, sqlite3.DatabaseError) and \
                orig.args == ('database is locked',):
                raise SerializationConflictError(e)
            else:
                raise

    return retry_tween
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. Although it's not 100% pretty, knowing that the locking is happening at the database level and that it is intelligent on what is considered a serialization error. I am having one problem though. I'm using the Pyramid scaffolding which uses pyramid_tm. In addition, my SQLAlchemy session is a scoped_session. I cannot .commit() it (although I think .flush() is doing the same thing in this particular case), and if I .rollback() then I can't retry the transaction: "ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed". I'm going to google around a bit. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the answer to cover the transaction middleware case.

Comment: I posted my previous "not 100% pretty" message before the awesome update you did. The tween idea is perfect. It nicely decouples everything. Perfect!

Is there any reason you raise a SerializationConflictError rather than a simple TransientError?

Comment: No, I just thought this adds a little bit of self-documentation.